# Допустимо ли выражение "толкать к себе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Я немного споткнулась об эту фразу. В моём представлении всегда было "толкать от себя", а не к себе. Мозг что-то отключился. Помогите разобраться, как правильно.

> И тут понимаю, что вторая рука его  уже на моей спине и он толкает
> меня к себе и целует в губы.

Comment: В таких случаях надо смотреть в словари и делать выводы ТОЛКАТЬ
Грамматика Семантика
Глагол, несовершенный вид, переходный
Коротким резким движением, толчком отодвигать, отстранять.

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо. У слова **толкнуть** есть значение **подтолкнуть**. `Подтолкнуть шарик ближе к себе.` Вы же не будете говорить `притянуть шарик ближе к себе`, ага.

Answer (score 1):

ТОЛКАТЬ изначально, глагол имеющий значение передвижение чего-то ОТ того, что толкает - ТОЛКАТЬ ОТ.

Но, по ряду причин, ТОЛКАТЬ приобрело также переносное значение ТОЛКАТЬ К/НА.

Ушаков, ТОЛКАТЬ:

> 4. перен., кого-что. Помогать кому-чему-н. идти нужным путем, содействовать своим вмешательством развитию чего-н. (разг.). Толкать
>    какое-н. дело. Он должен быть благодарен своему учителю, к-рый всегда
>    толкал его вперед.
> 5. перен., кого-что. Понукать, заставлять делать что-н. скорее, живее (разг.). Их надо толкать, а то к сроку ничего не будет сделано.
> 6. перен., кого-что на что или к чему. Побуждать к чему-н., служить причиной, поводом чьего-н. поступка (книжн.). Толкать на преступление.
>    «Весь ход экономического развития толкал к уничтожению крепостного
>    права.» История ВКП(б).

Он толкает меня / к себе - я бы так разбил фразу по смыслам.

Можно обособить "к себе", тогда не будет проблем с прямым значением:

*И тут понимаю, что вторая рука его уже на моей спине и он толкает меня, к себе, и целует в губы.*

Comment: Нет, текст нехорош!  Можно и не стараться сделать из него шедевр. Но и тематика сложная. Подобные сцены только хороший художник слова может изобразить, а иначе они выглядят, как бы это сказать, приторно-пошленькими. Так что уж лучше не толкаться))Я бы такое читать не стала, мне нужно что-нибудь символически-утонченное. Но к такому стилю толкание плохо походит.

Comment: И тут понимаю, что вторая рука его уже на моей спине и он толкает меня в неизвестность, целуя в губы... - так?

Comment: Может быть, если вам нравится.  А первая рука где? Трудно без контекста)

Comment: @Sharon Принц был однорук, первую руку потерял в сражении.

Comment: Надо об этом как-то упомянуть...)

Comment: @Sharon И тут понимаю, что вторая рука его уже на моей спине и однорукий господин толкает меня в неизвестность, целуя в губы... -так?

Comment: Ладно, пойдет.  В неизвестность можно толкать, разрешается)